# Error restarting httpd while installing phpmyadmin

Tags: amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, apache

After calling `sudo service httpd restart` I get the following error:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf:
Invalid command '\xe2\x80\xb9Directory', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

And here's my /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
‹Directory "/var/www/phpmyadmin"›
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
#SSLRequireSSL
‹/Directory›
```

Any thoughts? My site is now down, can't seem to find the issue.

FWIW this is running on an EC2 Linux instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<Directory>` and `</Directory>` tags are using single arrow quotes instead of less than and greater than signs. Compare the slight difference: `‹` `<`.

Simply replace those characters with the proper less than and greater than, and you should be fine:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
<Directory "/var/www/phpmyadmin">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    #SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
```